# remove redundance in compare-functions

Tags: javascript

I wrote some compare-functions that I pass to other methods in javascript:

```
function equal(a, b) {
    if (a instanceof Date) return a.getTime() == b.getTime();
    return a == b;
}

function lessThan(a, b) {
    if (a instanceof Date) return a.getTime() < b.getTime();
    return a < b;
}

function greaterThan(a, b) {
    if (a instanceof Date) return a.getTime() > b.getTime();
    return a > b;
}

function lessOrEqual(a, b) {
    return equal(a, b) || lessThan(a, b);
}

function greaterOrEqual(a, b) {
    return equal(a, b) || greaterThan(a, b);
}
```

Is there a way to get this a bit more compact? If I want to add another comparable type I always have to modify the first three functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to check if the variables are `instanceof Date`. **A dates value is its time** so when you make (less than/greater than) comparisons with a Date instance (`x`) you're essentially comparing it to `+x` or `x.valueOf()` which will be the same as `x.getTime()`. Therefore the below will always be equivalent:

```
function equal(a, b) {
    if (a instanceof Date && b instanceof Date) return +a == +b; //compare the 2 dates times as noted in the above statement +x == x.getTime() == x.valueOf()
    return a == b;
}

function lessThan(a, b) {
    return a < b;
}

function greaterThan(a, b) {
    return a > b;
}
```

Comment: new Date("2014-03-05") == new Date("2014-03-05")  and  new Date("2014-03-05").getTime() == new Date("2014-03-05").getTime()  are not the same.

Comment: new Date("2014-03-05") == new Date("2014-03-05")  returns false

Comment: @user2033412 ah you're right for that case

Comment: I like your new approach, now I can just write plus before every variable inside the functions and get rid of the typecheck.

Comment: You'll still need it for `equal`

Comment: no, because +new Date("2014-05-03") == +new Date("2014-05-03") returns true

Comment: I don't know the allowed inputs but consider `+window` or `+{test: 1}`

Comment: @user2033412 no need for `+a > +b` it will be handled internally. Also you may want to consider using `===` as `"" == 0`. Anyway I don't know what inputs you plan to give `equal` but you should be careful with `==`

Comment: I don't use defensive programming, I assume the programmer will check for the types and the bounds of the application.

Comment: Is it good style to override valueof in my own objects for comparison? Example: var test = (function (val) {

    var val = val;
    var name = "test";

    return {
        name: name,
        valueOf: function () { return val; }
    }
});

Comment: Thats not overriding `instanceOf` but setting `valueOf` is perfectly fine

Comment: Perfect! I'll go for +a === +b and overriding valueOf